# Charles iphone proxy

Tags: charles-proxy

I am trying to sniff traffic from some of my apps on the iphone.
I have charles installed. and i have installed the certificate on the iphone as instructed in charles (and i enabled the certificate on the iphone) + changes proxy to direct trafik from iphone to my computer through charles.

Everything works, i am getting trafik from the phone inside charles.

My problem is, all https called are failing for me. if i enable SSL proxy on a certain domain (let's take *.facebook.com for example) all requests give me a Failure    SSL: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?.

[image: screenshot of charles]

It does not matter which app or which connection i try, i get the same error..

can anyone help me

Comment: some of the other requests has the error "Failure Client SSL handshake failed: CA certificate could not be matched with a known, trusted CA (unknown_ca)" The certificate is enabled on the phone

Comment: Did you find how to solve it?

Comment: Nope, im pretty sure its because they pin their certificate

Answer (score 6):

Starting from iOS 10.3 *SSL trust for the certificate has to be turned on manually for the manually installed certificate profiles* in iOS so go to **Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings**. Under **Enable full trust for root certificates** turn on trust for the certificate.]]

Here is the link to apple [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477)